# Inserting a string into the first location of every list inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code:

```
frames = input("Enter a number")
lists = [[] for i in range(int(frames))]
```

My attempt:

```
for i in lists:
lists[0].insert(0,"Page Frame")
```

But that didn't give me the correct output

And I want to insert a string into the first index of each of the lists. For example: I want to insert `"Page Frame"`:

```
["Page Frame",0,0,0,0]
["Page Frame",0,0,0,0]
["Page Frame",0,0,0,0]
["Page Frame",0,0,0,0]
["Page Frame",0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Where do the `0`s come from?

Comment: Have you made any effort at all? The code you show is not related to your expected output...

Comment: The 0s are justa placeholder, there will be other data there

Comment: @MadPhysicistI edited the question with my attempt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
for list_ in lists:
    list_.insert(0, "page frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!

Comment: @PaulIacob no problem, consider accepting the answer if it worked :)

Comment: It's making me wait 5 mins, I will do it after

Comment: @PaulIacob alrighty

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
for lst in lists:
    lst.insert(0, "Page Frame")
```